# Does LogoutPath do anything?

Tags: c#, owin

I am writing a sample app. leveraging OWIN and `UseCookieAuthentication`. The latter accepts `CookieAuthenticationOptions`, which has a `LogoutPath` property. This property has the following associated note:

> If the LogoutPath is provided the middleware then a request to that path will redirect based on the ReturnUrlParameter.

However, I cannot figure out whether this does anything or if it just represents some implicit contract your code will do something. For example, if I leverage `AuthenticationManager.SignOut()`, I would expect the logout-path endpoint would get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the decompiled code of `Microsoft.Owin.Security` it is trying to perform a redirect, if the **LogOutPath** was specified. It will redirect to the **returnUrl** parameter in the query string. So to summarize again.

> If the current request matches your LogOutPath and it has a returnUrl parameter, the OWIN middleware will *automatically* redirect to the returnUrl specified in the query string. Otherwise it will do nothing.

Useful functionality might be, you logout and want to redirect back to the same page that now has degraded functionality for anonymous users.

```
    bool shouldLoginRedirect = num1 != 0;
        int num2;
        if (shouldSignout)
        {
          PathString logoutPath = this.get_Options().LogoutPath;
          // ISSUE: explicit reference operation
          if (((PathString) @logoutPath).get_HasValue())
          {
            num2 = PathString.op_Equality(((AuthenticationHandler) this).get_Request().get_Path(), this.get_Options().LogoutPath) ? 1 : 0;
            goto label_22;
          }
        }
        num2 = 0;
label_22:
        bool shouldLogoutRedirect = num2 != 0;
        if ((shouldLoginRedirect || shouldLogoutRedirect) && ((AuthenticationHandler) this).get_Response().get_StatusCode() == 200)
        {
          string str = ((AuthenticationHandler) this).get_Request().get_Query().Get(this.get_Options().ReturnUrlParameter);
          if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) && CookieAuthenticationHandler.IsHostRelative(str))
            this.get_Options().Provider.ApplyRedirect(new CookieApplyRedirectContext(((AuthenticationHandler) this).get_Context(), this.get_Options(), str));
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Khalid Abuhakmeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86411/khalid-abuhakmeh) for providing additional insight. However, my confusion ultimately is a result of assuming an implicit end-point is mapped when specifying the `LogoutPath` property. After adding the following, requesting `/logout?ReturnUrl=/` works as-expected:

```
app.Map("/logout", logout =>
{
    logout.Run(context =>
    {
        context.Authentication.SignOut();

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    });
});
```

Without the explicit map, I get a [404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404).

As an additional side-note, I also wrongly assumed providing an `AuthenticationProperties`-instance to `SignOut` would allow me to specify the return-url (instead of having it as part of the request url). It appears this only applies to [external cookie authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn782487%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).